# "AW8738 High Performance 4W Smart Amplifier driver". Kernel is not compiling

Tags: kernel, android-kernel

I added this "AW8738 High Performance 4W Smart Amplifier driver" but my kernel is not compiling. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Error: ../arch/arm64/boot/dts/qcom/msm8953-audio_rosy.dtsi:147.5-20 syntax error
FATAL ERROR: Unable to parse input tree
```

```
140:    qcom,wsa-max-devs = <2>;
141:      qcom,wsa-devs = <&wsa881x_211>, <&wsa881x_212>,
142:            <&wsa881x_213>, <&wsa881x_214>;
143:       qcom,wsa-aux-dev-prefix = "SpkrLeft", "SpkrRight",
144:                "SpkrLeft", "SpkrRight";
145:   };
147:     audio_amplifier {
148:           compatible = "aw,aw8738";
149:           ext-spk-amp-gpio = <&tlmm 139 0x0>;
150:  };
```